# a:hover for background area around an image

Tags: html, css, background, hover

I'd like to make the background area around the outside of an image change color when hovering over it. I'd like a similar result as the "related posts" at the bottom of the posts on my website. i.e.
http://www.livecrafteat.com/eat/chicken-and-stuffing-in-the-crockpot/

I'm using a text widget and ultimately want a row of 2 images of equal size that when hovered over have the background change like the YARR plugin at the bottom of my posts. I will have 6 rows of this table format and have tried to set it up to control them as cleanly as possible. I've tried to set up the following HTML and CSS respectively to make it work but am stuck - especially on the hover portion.

HTML:

```
<div class="popular-posts">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
<div class="pop-posts-left" width="160px" height="160px">
                    <td align="left" >
<div class="pop-posts-image-left"><a href="http://www.livecrafteat.com/live/meal-planning-template/"> <img src="http://www.livecrafteat.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/menu-plan-sidebar-thumbnail-2.jpg" />  </a></div>
</td>
</div>
<div class="pop-posts-right" width="160px" height="160px">
                    <td align="right">
<div class="pop-posts-image-right"><a href="http://www.livecrafteat.com/live/meal-planning-template/"> <img src="http://www.livecrafteat.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/menu-plan-sidebar-thumbnail-2.jpg" />  </a></div>
</td>
</div>
</tr>
</tbody>
</left>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pop-posts-left {
    background: red;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.pop-posts-right {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    background: orange;
}
.pop-posts-left a:hover {
}
.pop-posts-image-left a:hover {
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the ":hover" pseudo-class in your container. It can be used in conjunction with any selector, not only with the "a" tag selector, which is more common to see.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/pc78c/

Take a look in these docs too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:hover

Comment: I'll respond here but to all... thanks! First post here and didn't expect such a fast response from so many. I'll have to post the rest of my questions since I'm a noob.  Simply adding the :hover made it work how I wanted. Now just a matter of cleaning up my hackish looking html.

Comment: Spoke too soon.  It's worked perfectly but the top/bottom padding in FF is a little off. Right now I have it at 5px. But in FF the top looks more like 2 o 3 px and the bottom like 7 or 8. IE and Chrome render perfectly with a nice even border around the entire image. Being a noob I've seen some other answers on here how to fix this but how would I do so specific to my code? Is there something I can add to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dustin: Please, create another question for your problem. I think that if you "reset" your css. Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597674/why-is-ie9-ff-opera-adding-20-margin-vs-chrome/

Answer (score 0):

`.pop-posts-left:hover { background: green; }` should work (as an example). If you want hovering over one element to affect another, you'll probably need jQuery for that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for http://jsfiddle.net/MFx5E/1/ ?

```
.pop-posts-left:hover {
    background: green;
}
.pop-posts-image-left a:hover {
    background: green;
}
.pop-posts-right:hover {
    background: green;
}
.pop-posts-image-right a:hover {
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason, why you don't see the green `background-color` defined in your `.pop-posts-image-left a:hover` are caused of the non-transparent jpg image. Additionally didn't add some padding to `.pop-posts-image-left`.

In order to figure this out, just add the following and see what happens:

```
.pop-posts-image-left {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your html is actualy completly invalid.

- you have to place a  inside a
- should only contain , no  as you are doing
- there is a  underneath the  while you never opened it

Try fixing your html first, as this may mess up your results. Validating your code at the [W3C website](http://validator.w3.org/)  is also always a good idea.

After that the hover effect should be easy, just do something like @ChrisClower suggests